# Sikulix No module named Do

Tags: sikuli-script

When using 1.1.3 -- Sikuli works as expected, scripts are run without issue.
When using 2.0.5 (latest),
Sikuli IDE opens
Attempt any script, regardless if it's new or existing
The following error is thrown:

Exception in thread "Thread-39" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from Sikuli import *
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py", line 23, in 
import org.sikuli.script.Do as Do
ImportError: No module named Do

No changes have been made between versions of Sikuli

Sikuli is located in folder:   C:\SikuliX
containing: all setup info for 1.1.3
and sikulixide-2.0.5.jar

Can someone take a moment to solve my issue.

Tried various solutions to include setting environment variables.

Additional notes:   Within the Sikuli.py file here is the line item:

---

Debug.log(4, "Jython: sikuli: Sikuli: backports from Version 2: Do")
import org.sikuli.script.Do as Do

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- delete the folder `C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix` before running IDE 2.0.5
- do not mix up 1.1.3 and 2.0.5 on the same machine (at least do only run 1 version)
- make sure, that nothing belonging to 1.1.3 (except scripts) is seen by 2.0.5 (use separate top-level folders for 1.1.3 and 2.0.5)

If this does not help - no idea (2.0.5 is running well on my Win11)

RaiMan from SikuliX

Answer (score 0):

Found an obscure post from Raiman:

needed to the below info to allow Sikuli 2.0.5 to find the sikuli.py file in users
Added the below statement to the masterpath file and everything works again.

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/692917

ImportError no module named common

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).